# take out some fields key and values from the objects and transform into column structure, in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{ 
   "abc": {
      "value": "100",
      "print": "number1",
      "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
      "name" : "delta1",
      "service" : "31-12-2021",
      "type" : "typeA"
    },
    "xyz": {
      "value": "123",
      "print": "number2",
      "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
      "name" : "delta2",
      "service" : "31-12-2021",
      "type" : "typeB"

    }
}
```

**Explanation**:  `"abc"`, `"xyz"` these are my parameter, I am passing dynamically, it could be more than 2. but inside the objects the fields are static, I want to convert my data in the respective format that contains the only `name` and `value` fields as output. please check the Expected Output

**Expected Output.**

```
   [{
    "_id": null,
    "output": {
        "name": "delta1",
        "value": "100"
    }
}, {
    "_id": null,
    "output": {
        "name": "delta2",
        "value": "123"
    }
}]

|---------------------|------------------|
|      name           |       value      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      delta1         | 100              |                
|---------------------|------------------|
|      delta2         | 123              |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: can you share complete document, is the give sample part of a single document or are multiple documents

Comment: but I need only these 2 fields from the given parameter list `value` and  `name` from the documents. the document will be increased if I give more parameters, `abc` `xyz` these are parameters. The next one could be the `alpha`  parameter.

Comment: Yes but are these parameters part of one document or multiple, do you mind sharing your document / schema structure

Comment: yes, it's part one document,  I update my schema, just added more fields. but original structure is the same, I posted

Comment: Your expect output is not a valid JSON structure. Plz correct it! An object within an object with no key?

Comment: I just update it, thanks for the comment. I also work with the query and I come up with sol, https://mongoplayground.net/p/60MC1DVlh18 please check the link, but some how "$unwind" is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "testCollection",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "parameters"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            parameters: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: { $arrayElemAt: ["$parameters", 0] } },
                    as: "parameter",
                    in: {
                        k: "output",
                        v: {
                            $cond: {
                                if: { $ifNull: ["$$parameter.v.name", false] },
                                then: {
                                    "name": "$$parameter.v.name",
                                    "value": "$$parameter.v.value",
                                },
                                else: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$parameters" },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: [["$parameters"]] }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "output": { $ne: false }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Looks complicated I will try simplify it in next edit

Comment: I get your idea, I can simplify it, Thanks

Comment: If u simplify, update the answer. I it will help in understanding.